# Tikiwiki wiki improper links

Tags: php, wiki, twiki

I set up a tikiwiki site for my new project, however when i attempt to link directly to a wiki page, it goes to `http://sakuraengine.com/HomePage` rather than the proper url `http://sakuraengine.com/tiki-index.php?page=HomePage`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Personally, I would have thought that the first URL would have been the *far* better option.

Comment: What, since when clean URLs are NOT the preferred option? Better for users, better for search engines, everybody wins.

Comment: the issue isn't the url itself, i would love for that url to work. however i get an error 404 whereas the second one i do not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that i had to rename _htaccess to .htaccess to enable short urls. HAHA! fixed it immediately, now /homepage works

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the `search engine friendly url` option turned on. You should be able to disable this in your admin panel, though I don't see why you would want to do that.